# Why is Sagemath removed in Ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: 20.10, sagemath

This seems to be a regular occurrence, judging from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1199843/is-sagemath-removed-from-ubuntu-19-10) and [this one as well](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1003619/sagemath-in-ubuntu-17-10) but why does Sagemath not get packaged for 20.10?

Is it always left out of the October releases?

I've managed to install using their Linux binaries but it was a rather unpleasant surprise to upgrade and then discover that I've lost an important application.

Comment: From https://wiki.debian.org/DebianScience/Sage: "*Some people within DebianScience have again packaged Sage for Debian. This is one of the most complex packages in Debian and will need continual maintenance - we are always looking for new contributors!*" If you really want sagemath to be available, consider contributing some effort to the Debian Science Team.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sagemath in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1003619/sagemath-in-ubuntu-17-10) TL;DR: Too many dependencies, not enough contributors

Comment: I suspected as much. But wondering if there's any official policy to only bother packaging for LTS; i.e., if there's a predictable pattern to when it does/doesn't get included (LTS only?) or if it's just a case of doing it when the dependencies work out.

Comment: It's a case of who will step up to put in the work.  Usually this is left to the developers of the software (package maintainers).  There are only a handful of packages that are actually maintained by Canonical (the company behind Ubuntu) and those tend to be system critical packages like the kernel, package manager, security, etc. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software and https://askubuntu.com/questions/89400/who-compiles-all-the-packages-that-are-part-of-ubuntu

Comment: If it's truly "one of the most complex packages", the package maintainers may have decided that it's not worth the effort ($) and time ($$) to support the software on standard releases, since they come out every 6 months.  But you still might be able to compile from source: https://www.sagemath.org/download-linux.html